# checkout in USD - magento 1.9

Tags: checkout, paypal

I have a store whose base currency is EGP, have 2 display currencies: EGP & USD.

I want to make sure that whatever the display currency is, that the checkout is made in USD, since this is the only acceptable currency in PAYPAL & 2CO which i use on my website.

I really need help, need to put my website online asap.

Comment: Then you need to change the base currency to USD - it's pretty simple.

Comment: Serpye you should add this as an answer

Comment: You lot don't like one liners (as reminded by the mods) - even though it answers the question - so we don't bother any more.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System - Configuration - Currency setup and change what you need there. Change Base currency to the currency you want to use for operations, you will see some more info in the comment of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Online transaction always made in Base Currency. Display currency used only to allow customer to see prices in his local currency.

PayPal support multiple currencies and is not limited to USD only, see multiple currencies list on PayPal website - https://www.paypal.com/multicurrency